# I have slow video acceleration, is there any way to fix this?

Tags: 11.04, ati, graphics

I have a an x700 mobility, and can't seem to find the drivers. I have the default Gallium drivers, but I would like to have proprietary drivers. Is there any way to do this on 11.04?

Answer (score 1):

[According to AMD](http://support.amd.com/us/gpudownload/Pages/index.aspx) your chip is no longer supported by their Catalyst driver. There is a legacy driver available but it intended for distributions predating February 2009 and may not work with newer distributions.

If you are experiencing slow framerates with games I suggest you disable some of the effects.